# Remove parentheses from category counts in wordpress and exclude category

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-list-categories

I'm using the following code to remove the parentheses from category counts in Wordpress which works fine however the &exclude=10 to exclude a category no longer works.

```
<?php
 $variable = wp_list_categories('echo=0&show_count=1&title_li=&exclude=10');
 $variable = str_replace(array('(',')'), '', $variable);
 echo $variable;
?>
```

Comment: If you disable the `str_replace` the code works? Funny thing...

Comment: according to the docs, exclude is an accepted parameter. if it doesn't work you should file a bug at wordpress.org. also, they recommend using a regex to remove the parentheses (http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Remove_Parentheses_from_Category_Counts), I suppose to avoid deleting parentheses on category names

Comment: @Einacio, I like the message in your profile page ;) Amazing, the docs have a specific entry for this.

Comment: Switched it to regex and still not working.

Comment: Definitely a bug details here on the Trac here.
[link]https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25710

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$args = array(
    'echo'       => 0,
    'taxonomy'   => 'category',
    'exclude'    => 10,
    'hide_empty' => 1,
    //'parent'     => 0  //uncomment this if you only want top level cats
);
$cats = get_categories($args);
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($cats as $cat) :
   echo '<li><a href="'.get_category_link( $cat->term_id ).'">'.$cat->name.'</a></li>';
endforeach;
echo '</ul>';
```

WP bug bypassed with different function that essentially does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The code that works: Make sure it goes into your Functions.php file.

```php
hadd_filter( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', 'wc_filter_woocommerce_subcat_count_html', 10, 2 );
function wc_filter_woocommerce_subcat_count_html( $mark_class_count_category_count_mark, $category ) {
$mark_class_count_category_count_mark = ' <mark class="count">' . $category->count . '</mark>';
return $mark_class_count_category_count_mark;
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can generally be improved by adding explanation of how and why they work. When adding an answer to a question with an accepted answer it is important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses and if the passage of time and new versions of WordPress have changed the answer.